# salt-master not working yet error while setting up kubernetes cluster on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to create a Kubernetes Cluster on an AWS EC2 instance using [this guide](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setup-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-ec2/).  I am getting the following errors:

```
Attempt 1 to check for SSH to master [ssh to master working]
Attempt 1 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 2 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 3 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 4 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 5 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 6 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 7 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 8 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 9 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 10 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 11 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
Attempt 12 to check for salt-master [salt-master not working yet]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/6570) this is most likely a problem with your SSH key

Comment: Well I tried changing the ssh key based on  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/6570 link. Still it doesn't work.